# SSL on TCPListener

Tags: c#, ssl, server, tcplistener

I have a server application based on TCPListener which receives messages from alarm panels every 5 sec. Currently SLL is not introduced in my application because the messages are not that confidential (e.g. 1000XA001 which identifies the sender and message type). I am wondering if this will cause security breach or this is totally fine without SSL. I am also wondering introducing SLL might cause delay to the high number of messages received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this - without TLS (SSL) you do not know if the message that you have received was really originated by the node you think it was originated and that it was not changed during transmition. Since you are using this for alarm panels - how do you know that the code ('No Alarm'/'All OK') is really what was sent by the alarm panel?

The only way to know if TLS will add delay is to test. I would not worry about the increase in delay on the server side. The only factor here is how much computational resources alarm panels have.

Adding TLS will increase the communication channel setup time by a small margin.

EDIT to answer a question:

You must enable SSL on both server and the panel to make it secure. It is not enough to have SSL enabled on a server only.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My another question is that because I cannot intervene the alarm panels, is it enough just to have the SSL on the server to make the communication secure? Thanks.